# azure sdk2.5 cloud service deployment not create wad-control-container blob

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

While deploying the cloud service using azure sdk 2.5 from Visual studio 2013 edition, it deployed successfully. But it did not create the `wad-control-container` blob container under diagnostics storage account.

Previous version Azure SDK 2.2 created `wad-control-container` but not with the latest sdk.

A few questions regarding this:

- I saw MSDN documentation, they told that this container is no longer used. Then how it takes the role instance id details?
- And how it will work internally? Previously wad-control-container is the high precedence storage then it will store these details to WadPerformanceCountersTable based on configuration.
- Now, where that configuration file located on azure storage account?
- Imperative code approach starts the DiagnsosticsMonitor agent(will store the performance counters). But declarative approach (configuration file .wadcfg) also do the same thing with out create the wad-control-container table.

Please clarify my doubts.

Comment: Azure configuration details that is roleinstance count, roleinstane value and deployment id where to be stored. I want to get the azure deployment id details for particular storage account with cloud service name.  Please send any azure sdk for getting those details. Expect your valuable response/help.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your questions can be found on the following pages:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2014/12/02/windows-azure-diagnostics-upgrading-from-azure-sdk-2-4-to-azure-sdk-2-5/

http://www.rajinders.com/2015/05/03/azure-sdk-2-6-diagnostics-improvements-for-cloud-services/

In short, the configuration for a deployment lives within that deployment as opposed to being stored in a storage account.

You need to set your diagnostics configuration in an XML file (diagnostics.wadcfgx).  wad-control-container and code (for example, the API in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.Management) don't affect the configuration anymore - only the XML file does.  Old code will still compile with build warnings which will inform you of the deprecated APIs. The diagnostics data will not be collected unless you configure your diagnostics using the XML file, though.